# Android 10+ not retrieving DATE_TAKEN information from MediaStore

Tags: java, android

When downloading images from browser and listing them into the app, date taken column is always null only on android 10+

```
ArrayList<String> localImages = new ArrayList<>();

Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().build();

final String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED
};
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

String searchQuery = null;//dateQuery == null ? null : MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + ">" + (dateQuery.getTime());
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, searchQuery, null, orderBy + " DESC");

int columnIndexData = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
int columnDateTaken = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndexData);
    String dateTaken = cursor.getString(columnDateTaken); // THIS IS ALWAYS NULL
    localImages.add(imagePath);
}
```

Comment: .DATA column cannot be used under Android Q.

Comment: I have a deprecation warning on this, but that's not really the problem

Comment: If you use Chrome you should inform there why they dont fill it in. I think because a browser has no idea about that date.

Answer (score 0):

"[Media Store insert DATE_TAKEN is always null](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140250785)"

> DATE_TAKEN is documented to be "The time the media item was taken." and to deliver on that API description, we populate it based on the "DateTimeOriginal" Exif metadata field, or the .  If the file being scanned doesn't have this metadata, we can't accurately determine when the file was captured, so DATE_TAKEN is set to NULL to avoid misleading data.

So, some devices don't have `DATE_TAKEN` field.If you use `DATE_TAKEN`, you will check value is **null or not**. And when not, you should fall back to use `DATE_ADDED` or `DATE_MODIFIED`, etc.

I referred to this Japanese article: https://zenn.dev/tsutou/articles/59fbb5e71b2988